# How to read selected text on richTextBox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, selectedtext

There is a richTextBox that has string. I want to select a few characters on the richTexBox by mouse and save them in a variable. I use this method:

```
richTextBox1.SelectedRtf;
```

It shows me selected characters but is has some additional string and i don't want them. How can I remove them?

This is additional string:
{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1256\deff0\deflang1065\uc1 }

Comment: What is the actual output you want from that string?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: what output you want and what actually comes.. Please write that too. It will be more clear.

Comment: WPF, WinForms, WinRT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
 richTextBox1.SelectedText
```

Here is the msdn link for more information
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Selection.Text property will return the selected text of Rich Edit Text box.

```
richTextBox1.Selection.Text
```

Answer (score 1):

RichTextBox.SelectedText? may be?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

use this

richTextBox1.SelectedText (property)